# Hotlink protection facebook not getting images

Tags: html, facebook, apache, security, http

Basically today someone has been stealing bandwidth from me, 750GB in the past 8 hours. I have enabled hotlink protection on the CDN I use, however since I enabled it, facebook can't seem to pull the images from my website. 
    og:image

I have tried to allow these domains:
    *.facebook.com
    facebook.com
    fbcdn.com
    *.fbcdn.com

However still no luck. Just wondering if anyone had an idea of how to get this working

Kind regards

Comment: When people steal bandwidth from me, a firearm and a couple mean words usually does the trick. For personal health reasons, though, I wouldn't suggest my method.

Comment: Thanks lol, I would prefer the peaceful approach first :)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#scraperinfo

Comment: Had a look on that link, cant really see anything on there I can use :S

Comment: _"750GB in the past 8 hours"_ Are you sure you're not being DDoS-ed!? And if you are using `.htaccess` to prevent hot-inking create a new directory for `OG:Images`

Comment: Yeah it isnt DDOS, server is running fine and load is low, however not sure what you mean by create new directory for OG:Images, currently I am using MaxCDN and I have turned on hotlink protection, Ive added the fb domains to the list so it doesnt block them from retrieving the images however it doesnt seem to be working, just wondering If i have the correct domains listed or am I missing the right one.

Comment: You could try their debug tool to see how they see your site: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug not sure if that'd help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allow access to the IP address ranges described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper, or to all requests with a User-Agent of "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"